SUR in Pooled OLS
Let's say you have a sample size of 150 consisting of five separate entities, whose characteristics are samples, and the entities are assumed to have common explanatory variables.

Homoskedasticity: null hypothesis cannot be rejected
Fixed or random effects: eliminated by demeaning t and t-1
Estimation method: pooled OLS on demeaned data with common shock dummy variable as an explanatory variable.

If SUR yields significantly better p-values, would reporting this result be an example of p-hacking or legitimate since error correlations between entities may still exist but are unaccounted for, especially given the relatively small sample size?
